# Django multiple schemas with foreign keys on each

Tags: python, django, postgresql

So I have a database that has multiple schemas in django. One schema holds the api service end if you will, while the other schema has the cms and user information. How do I reference items from the other schema? postgres spits up a

```
relation "" does not exist
```

The trouble is that I need items on each schema for foreign keys. Any hacky solutions are welcome, as I believe I am dealing with a poorly put together project.

Comment: Are you attempting to merge the schemas?  (I would suggest it if possible.)

Comment: show some code please